# different font for mathcal while using mathpazo+eulervm

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, mathcal, eulervm

I have been using `mathpazo` + `eulervm` for my LaTeX documents and I'm very happy with the results, with one exception:  The characters for `\mathcal` do not come out the way I want; I prefer the `\mathcal` font under `mathpazo` alone.  Two  *independent* questions:

1. Is there a way to use the `\mathcal` fonts under `mathpazo` for the entire `mathpazo`+`eulervm` document?
2. Is there a way to use the `\mathcal` fonts under `mathpazo` for a *specific* letter for the entire `mathpazo`+`eulervm` document?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\mathcal` version defined by `mathpazo` is given by

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbols}
```

These and other math fonts definitions are of course overwritten by the ones of `eulervm`, so the only thing `mathpazo` is doing there is using a Palatino font for text. (For that you might want to switch to TeX Gyre Pagella or New PX, but that's a matter of taste.)

If you don't mind wasting a math alphabet you can adapt the lines given above to something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathpazocal}{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

% eulervm version
$\mathcal{ABCDE}$ {\boldmath$\mathcal{ABCDE}$}

% mathpazo version for one single symbol
$\mathpazocal{ABCDE}$ {\boldmath$\mathpazocal{ABCDE}$}

% make them synonyms
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mathcal}[1]{\mathpazocal{#1}}
$\mathcal{ABCDE}$ {\boldmath$\mathcal{ABCDE}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works!  Follow up questions:    (1) Could you clarify what you meant by "wasting a math alphabet"?   (e.g. as in defining a new function \mathpazocal ?)    (2) What are the difference between mathpazo vs newpx vs TeX Gyre Pagella, besides the (to my eyes) slight stylistic difference?  (e.g. "newer", more compatible with other packages, etc?)    Thanks!

Comment: @underflow (1) There are only 16 slots for math alphabets. Loading many math fonts might lead you to hit this limit. (It never happened to me but it can.) (2) As you say, stylistic differences. `mathpazo` is somewhat older, the other two are actively mantained.